# How relevant are theoretical convex optimization convergence rates in practice, when parameters are unknown and function may be nonconvex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

There are many theoretical results known on convergence rates for various (possibly stochastic) convex optimization problems. For example, the popular review on optimization algorithms for machine learning [https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4980] gives many such rigorous results.

For example, say we have a constraint set with diameter $R$, and we have stochastic access to an objective function with gradient estimates upper bounded by $G$. Then, one can rigorously prove that projected SGD, with proper step sizes, converges at a rate $O(RG/\sqrt{T})$.

I am wondering how relevant theoretical results such as this are in practice, where relevant parameters may be unknown. In the above example, the step sizes of SGD must be chosen wisely (as functions of $R$ and $G$) to attain the provable convergence rate. But, say that my optimization problem is actually complicated and nonconvex, and I run some SGD algorithm on it. Say that I start SGD in some convex region containing a local minimum, at distance $R$ from the true optimum. However, my algorithm doesn't know that it is distance $R$ from the optimum. Also, I might not a priori know a bound $G$ on the gradient estimates I receive. In practice, can I still run some SGD algorithm and converge to the optimum at a rate $O(RG/\sqrt{T})$?

The above paragraph is a specific example, but I'm just generally curious about how well provable converge rates carry over in practice to complicated nonconvex optimization problems (where, say, one is satisfied to converge to any local minimum to high precision).

Comment: For nonconvex problems, you might want to look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06523.pdf).

Comment: Convergence proofs have no value in practice, even for convex functions. The bounds are too weak, so implementations rarely follow theory

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @LinAlg , if convergence proofs have no value in practice, what is their purpose? Do you truly mean they have _no_ value, or just that there is often a large difference between theory and practice? Does the theory not at least guide our expectations for practical applications?

Comment: @M.Eieals I am sure some people can appreciate convergence proofs. Let me given an example. For linear optimization there are the simplex method and an interior point method. Only the latter has proven polynomial complexity, but the implementations often do not. In practice the simplex method can be much faster or much slower, depending on the linear optimization model and data.

Comment: The major problem with convergence rate proofs is that the theory has not evolved enough yet to provide a useful bound. For example, many first-order methods are proved to converge at $O(1/k^2)$ rate, where $k$ is the number of iterations, but in practice linear convergence is observed in many cases. Moreover, the constants in the bound are far from being tight, and are of no practical value.

In many cases, the rate of convergence proof is useful to get intuition - a method with a substantially faster rate than a competitor, in many cases, is indeed faster in practice when implemented well.

Comment: There's the "]" inside the link.